# Embedded has many relationship not always working

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, relationship

I have a `ticket` model that has a property for `ticket_holders` that is a `hasMany` relationship

```
ticket_holders: DS.hasMany('ticket-holder'),
```

The `ticket-holder` model has a `ticket` property defined as a `belongsTo`

```
ticket: DS.belongsTo('ticket')
```

In the `ticket` serializer I defined the `EmbeddedRecordsMixin` and set the `attrs` property like so

```
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin,{
    attrs: {
        ticket_holders: {embedded: 'always'}
    },
    ...
```

An example `ticket` from the API looks like this

```
{
   "eid":"5060",
   "user_id":"13193",
   "ticket_id":"612",
   "ticket_purchase_code":"1ab9e0f20178220a75d5d2ca18322efa",
   "ticket_purchase_behalf_name":null,
   "ticket_purchase_behalf_email":null,
   "ticket_name_alias":null,
   "ticket_cost":"0.00",
   "ticket_ticketing_time":"2015-11-17 11:24:32",
   "ticket_qty":"1",
   "ticket_total":"1.00",
   "ticket_paid":"1",
   "ticket_transaction_id":"noch_5060564b54c0c42ffy0M8tpk",
   "ticket_validation_phrase":"",
   "ticket_pay_type":"card",
   "ticket_qty_redeemed":"0",
   "ticket_refunded":"0",
   "ticket_promo_code_used":"",
   "ticket_name":"Ticket #2",
   "ticket_purchase_user_name":"Tony Stark",
   "ticket_holders":[
      {
         "holder_code":"hc_299dc35e",
         "holder_user_id":"0",
         "holder_id":"8181",
         "holder_name":"Jordan again",
         "holder_email":"Riser.jordan@gmail.com",
         "holder_phone":"",
         "holder_paddle_number":"4888",
         "holder_rsvp":"0",
         "holder_redeemed":"1",
         "holder_last_updated":"2016-05-13 19:07:13",
         "ticket_qrcode":"barcode\/barcode.processor.php?encode=QRCODE&bdata=&qrdata_type=link&qr_link_link=http%3A%2F%2Fbidr.co%2Fl%2F8qexEa&height=500&scale=2&bgcolor=%23ffffff&color=%231B3448&file=&folder&type=png&Genrate=Create+Barcode&ECLevel=L&margin=",
         "ticket_pdf":"http:\/\/bidr.co\/ticket\/pdf_ticket.php?s1=1ab9e0f20178220a75d5d2ca18322efa&s2=hc_299dc35e"
      },
      ...
   ]
}
```

The primaryKey for a `ticket` is set to `primaryKey: 'ticket_purchase_code',` so in the normalize function for the store method I'm using I loop over each `ticket` grab it's `ticket_purchase_code` and then loop over each `ticket`'s `ticket_holders` array and set a new property on each called `ticket_purchase_code` to the one I got from it's parent `ticket` record.

It seems that `ticket-holder`'s are not always being attributed to the `ticket` when I attempt to loop over the `ticket` and then it's `ticket_holders` in the template

```
{{#each tickets as |purchase|}}
...
    {{#each purchase.ticket_holders as |ticket|}}
    ...
    {{/each>
{{/each}}
```

Sometimes I only see one `ticket-holder` under each `ticket` sometimes I see all the correct `ticket-holder`'s under each `ticket`, but more consistently I'm only seeing one `ticket-holder` under each `ticket`

Do I have my relationships set up wrong?

I have also tried changing the `ticket_purchase_code` on each `ticket_holder` that I loop over in the `ticket` serializer to `ticket_id` to see if that would work but it's not working correctly either.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this before myself Jordan. For me the situation was that **I had *2* *tickets* that both had the same ticket-holder**, i.e., `"ticket_id":"612"` and `"ticket_id":"633"` both have  `"holder_id":"8181"`. By the nature of a `belongsTo` poor `"holder_id":"8181"` can only be linked to a single ticket, so only the last ticket to load into ember-data that has `"holder_id":"8181"` will get to keep him.

**The Solution**
Trying commenting out `DS.belongsTo('ticket')` in ticket-holder, and see if they all load in like you'd expect.

```
 // Try commenting the ling below out
 ticket: DS.belongsTo('ticket')
```

Example, in this http://jsbin.com/sevipa/1/edit?html,js,output ,

```
 App.Contact = DS.Model.extend({
    name : DS.attr('string'),
     // Turn the below on to see your problem. Matt H belongsTo 2 different companies
     //company : DS.belongsTo('Company')
 });
```

I commented out the relationship to `company : DS.belongsTo('Company')` so that Matt H will show up in both the first 2 companies. If you put the line back in, you will see that he only continues to belongTo Johns Shoe Repair since it loads into ember-data after Housing4Hope.

Comment: I will give this a shot, I'm also merging two ember data sets together which will have similar data to each other but not necessarily the same data. Ie. one call will have all that the other call has but it may also have a few more records that will look similar, so I'm using `computed.uniq` to make sure there are not duplicates, not sure but this may have something to do with it too. I made sure both sets look EXACTLY the same and also removed the relationship in `ticket-holder` to see. I can't consistently get it to break but it seems to be working every time I refresh the data so far.

Comment: Yeah, play around with it a little bit and let me know.